# Tokens not correctly added to msg.sender

Tags: balances, tokens

This is the result of adding  500 tokens  to msg.sender

```
  function addTokens()  internal{
      uint256 _value = 500 ;
      balances[msg.sender]+=_value;
```

The result

```
0.000000000000000500
```

Answer (score 1):

It is adding it correctly, you need to take into consideration the decimals which in this case is 18. You would need to assign _value to be 500e18 (500 followed by 18 decimal points). Also, by initializing the variable _value with the amount of tokens you want the function to assign the msg.sender and then adding _value to the balances mapping, this is costing unnecessary gas. You are better of just writing: balances[msg.sender] += 500e18;